# Windows Task Scheduler Issues

Tags: windows, oracle, scheduled-tasks

I have scheduled windows task scheduler to upload different text files to oracle database. Till date its working fine. But i have an issue that if any uploading was disrupted because of following reasons.
1) Database Machine Shutdown
2) Internet Connectivity Issues
3) Miscellaneous

How i will get this information about failure of task scheduled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows itself (in the event log; a filtered view for each scheduled task is available in the Task Scheduler application) will record if the task failed.

For anything more you'll need to add diagnostic logging to your task's implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by diagnostic logging? Doi have to implement my own script to check how particular task is completed?

Comment: @ShekharNalawade: No. You need to change the implementation of the task to log its outcome or errors usefully.

Comment: How would you do that but? There is no option as such which can help us to track the above-mentioned things. 
1) Database Machine Shutdown 
2) Internet Connectivity Issues 
3) Miscellaneous

Comment: @ShekharNalawade The task is set to run something. That something needs to change to give you the information you need.

Comment: thanks for the insight. That means I have to modify my scripts which are scheduled with the help of task scheduler